# Setting a Boolean to null from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreferences` to store user settings/options.

I have added a new option that can be on or off and so want to store this as a `boolean` in my shared preferences file.

That is all good, however as this is a new option I want to set my internal variable to `null` if the option hasn't been explicitly set by the user (this way I can prompt for their choice when the new version is run for the first time).

The following doesn't work because getBoolean expects the primitive `boolean` as the default value to return if the preference isn't foudn in `shared+prefs`.

```
myNewSetting = shared_prefs.getBoolean("my_mew_setting",null);
```

In the above `myNewSetting` is a `Boolean` which *can* be set to `null`, but this doesn't help because of `getBoolean`s requirements.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method getBoolean returns a primitive boolean, so even you assign it to a Boolean, it just boxes it. The definition of the method is:

> abstract boolean  getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue)

If you really want to distinguish the case where the settings does not exist, just check if it is present or not:

```java
   if (!shared_prefs.contains("my_mew_setting"))
      myNewSetting = null;
   else
      myNewSetting = shared_prefs.getBoolean("my_mew_setting", true /* never use default value in this code because of the if condition */);
```

Comment: That's uch better than my bodge of storing as a string pref which can be read as a defult of null and then setting my Boolean based on that. Thanks, I'd forgotten about `.contains()`!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to require a null return you can proceed through an object. It will be a solution to adjust and use the related control value (Boolean) in the object according to your operation. The parcelable process is required for your respective class.In the current situation, unfortunately returning null will not work. Since the default value expects a primitive type, it must be true or false.